# Regex different type of strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string where I need to get a part from it, but the string can be different.

This are some of the string options:

```
"{{concentration=1}} charname=Mirajane \"Mira\" Felgrove"

"{{concentration=1}} {{charname=Mirajane \"Mira\" Felgrove}}"

"charname=Mirajane \"Mira\" Felgrove {{concentration=1}}"
```

Is there anyway I can get only the following part?

```
Mirajane \"Mira\" Felgrove
```

Thanks.

Edit: I'm working in JS at the moment. The charname can be anything; letters, numbers, spaces, other characters, and it can be on different places within the string and with or without {{}} surrounded.

Comment: What are the requirements? What tool or language? What have you tried?

Comment: @revo I'm sorry, don't use regex very often (I should realy look into it) and thought that there was no difference in language.

I'm working in JS at the moment.

The charname can be anything letters, numbers, spaces, other characters, and it can be on different places within the string and with or without {{}} surrounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RegEx [`(?<=charname=)[^\n{}]*[^"\n{}]`](https://regex101.com/r/8DkfQn/2)

- `(?<=charname=)` makes sure `charname=` is before your match
- `[^\n{}]*` matches anything but a `newline`, `{` or `}` 0 or more times.
- `[^"\n{}]` makes sure the last char isn't a `"`, `newline`, `{` or `}`

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/8DkfQn/2)

Comment: How did you know that OP's end regex flavor supports lookbehinds?

Comment: I didn't. I'm just posting a solution. If it doesn't solve OP's issue, he's free to tell me so.

Comment: When a question's tagged with regex only, it means OP failed to clear a language or a tool or a regex flavor. If you are spending your time to provide a good answer, if you care about this time being spent, ask for clarification beforehand. Lookbehinds are not supported in regex flavor (JS) you selected in regex101 either. Just Chrome has a support for it right now which means OP will see an error if they are using another browser like Firefox.

Comment: I love the solution, it doesn't work for me indeed because I'm using JS. I should've been more clear.

Comment: @RobinKuiper In this case use `charname=([^\n{}]*[^"\n{}])` instead, and get `$1`.

Comment: @Zenoo ah yes, was thinking about splitting it after, but that should work to, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of different regex could match those string and give you the expected result. Maybe you need to define the use case more accurately.

One of the simplest possibilities I see is the following:

```
charname=([A-Za-z\"]+\s+[A-Za-z\"]+\s+[A-Za-z\"]+)
```

It looks for the litteral "charname=" followed by 3 strings of letters and quotes, and captures all of this except "charname=".
This solution is not very robust though.

[image: Results on Regex101 tester]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm working in JS at the moment. The charname can be anything letters, numbers, spaces, other characters, and it can be on different places within the string and with or without {{}} surrounded.